# Attaching an event handler to a Com event: InvalidOperationException (S7-PLCSIM)

Tags: c#, events, com, plc

I'm trying to attach an Event Handler to an Event of a [COM Object](https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/855/1139855/att_29422/v1/S7WSPSCA.pdf). But I get an InvalidOperationException.

```
using S7PROSIMLib;

private S7ProSim ps = new S7ProSim();

ps.Connect();
ps.SetScanMode(ScanModeConstants.SingleScan);
ps.BeginScanNotify();

try {
    ps.ScanFinished += Ps_ScanFinished;
    //IS7ProSimEvents_ScanFinishedEventHandler scanFinishedDelegate = new IS7ProSimEvents_ScanFinishedEventHandler(Ps_ScanFinished);
    //ps.ScanFinished += scanFinishedDelegate;
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Source);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
}

private void Ps_ScanFinished(object ScanInfo)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Event fired");
}
```

The Output is:

```
event invocation for COM objects requires event to be attributed with DispIdAttribute
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComAwareEventInfo.GetDataForComInvocation(EventInfo eventInfo, Guid& sourceIid, Int32& dispid)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComAwareEventInfo.AddEventHandler(Object target, Delegate handler)
   at PiPLCSimBridge.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\PiPLCSimBridge\Form1.cs:Line 72.
```

I have also tried to use the commented out code, but got the same Exception.

Attaching the events like this should work, a popular Tool using the same COM interface [is doing it this way.](http://sourceforge.net/p/nettoplcsim/code/HEAD/tree/branches/multiinstace/nettoplcsim/csharp/NetToPLCSim/NetToPLCSim/PLCSim.cs#l49)

What is wrong with my Code?

Comment: Are you trying to connect a RaspberryPi to a 300/400 simulator?

Comment: Yes, how could you tell?:D

Comment: :)  That sounds pretty neat. Are you trying to use the Pi as remote IO or something? Are you interested in help with the project?

Comment: Yes, I plan to use it to extend the Simulation to the real world. Some help would be great, how can I contact you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As luck would have it, I recently encountered this exact same error with this exact same COM library.

The problem is caused by the `Embed Interop Types` setting in the prosim reference.

I discovered this fact via the discussion
[here.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/39edc2f3-781b-48c6-8e5f-f170ef00b10e/why-does-the-embed-interop-types-option-not-generate-the-appropriate-dispidattributes-in-some?forum=clr)

So, in the project references section, check the properties for the prosim reference. Make sure `Embed Interop Types` is not set.